# .NET Core stopped working from the command line AND from visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I ran into this problem when trying to install [.NET Core Tools 1.1](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases/tag/v1.1). The install succeeded, but now whenever I try to open a project that uses dotnet core, I get this error message in VS2015:
[image: Unable to start the process.]

Following that, any attempt to run the project results in a much vaguer "Unable to start debugging" error.

I tried working from the command line, and the results weren't any better:

```
λ dotnet build
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\RedistList\FrameworkList.xml' is denied.

λ dotnet restore
log  : Restoring packages for C:\(...)\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in C:\(...)\project.json...
log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\(...)\project.lock.json
error: Access to the path 'C:\(...)\project.lock.json' is denied.
```

Directories obfuscated for privacy reasons.

I checked the files that it's throwing errors trying to access - FrameworkList.xml is fully accessible and editable, and project.lock.json doesn't even exist.

Steps I've already tried in resolving one or both of these problems:

- Restarting Visual Studio
- Running VS in admin mode
- Restarting computer
- Manually inserting a project.lock.json file populated with data from someone else's copy of the same file in the same project
- Deleting the entire project and recloning it fresh from Github
- Reverting to the previous version of .NET Core
- Repairing the installation of .NET Core
- Uninstalling and reinstalling .NET Core completely
- Manually changing the permissions of the entire project folder to full control for all users
- Manually specifying a .NET Core version in global.json

Nothing helps, I keep getting the same error messages over and over no matter how far I try to set everything back to how it was before the install. Is there some last step I've somehow overlooked?

Comment: Check your installation directory for the existence of that sdk in the sdk folder.  That's the only thing I can think to suggest.  Also delete any newer versions completely from that folder.  That has helped me before.

Comment: There's only one folder in the sdk directory, and it matches the version number above exactly.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the VS2015 tools?  They are separate from the .NET core installation and it is not clear from your list if you did that or just the SDK.

Comment: I removed everything, including the tools, and reinstalled all of them. No fix.

Comment: Have you seen [this GH issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/629)?

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked on this:

- Close VS
- Delete all `project.lock.json` files
- Delete all `bin` and `obj` folders
- `dotnet restore --no-cache`
- Change global.json to specify SDK version `1.0.0-preview2-003131` instead of `1.0.0-preview2-003121`